# Is there any possibility to create profiles of displays interdependence in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, display, multiple-monitors

I have 3 displays. I use 2 of them always in normal horisontal (landscape) orientation, but I use the 3rd display sometimes in horisontal (landscape) and sometimes in vertical (portrait) orientaion.

Each time when I rotate the 3rd display I have to open display parameters in Windows, change orientaion of display and then adjust positions of displays between each other to reach needed configuration.

Also I can do the same in Nvidia control panel.

Is there any possibility to create and save profiles of displays interdependence to quickly switch between them? Standard Windows and Nvidia control panel do not provide such possibility.

Maybe there is some 3rd party software or some registry trick.

Comment: Never tried this software....https://sourceforge.net/projects/monitorswitcher/

Comment: If Nvidia Nview is installed this is  what you use to store profiles (I think)...if not download here.....https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/solutions/nview-display/

Comment: could you please create an answer for the questions so th that I could mark it as a right answer... I can do it myself, but your answer will increase your rating:)

Comment: Software recommendations are not considered answers here at SU. This is why they have the comments section.

Comment: @Moab Then why is [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/150988) part of our site FAQ?